# How to run faster? Velocity vs foot on floor

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, everyday-life, speed, biology

I was wondering how you can increase your running speed depending on how you set your foot on the floor.
In other words, how does the position of the foot area on the floor influence the speed/momentum of a person running?

Comment: It's complicated. [The Training and Development of Elite Sprint Performance: an Integration of Scientific and Best Practice Literature](https://sportsmedicine-open.springeropen.com/articles/10.1186/s40798-019-0221-0)

Answer (score 2):

Other than running on the balls of your feet, I don't think there are any other ways you can increase your speed. But there are other methods such as decreasing the drag on your body and leaning forward to shift your center of mass. Just observe nature; there are lots you can learn from it.

Answer (score 1):

It is my understanding that the angle of the foot is not the primary indicator of running speed. That is: you might be asking the wrong question. In case you are not: there may be some college professor who will be willing to take measurements, and give you a concrete answer...

What I know:

1. I have seen documentaries about the science of running that state the non-intuitive fact that the greater the impact of the foot with the ground, the faster the runner.
2. Strength and flexibility of the leg muscles is obviously important.
3. The training is quite different for long distance running, versus sprinting. I know that one exercise to improve your sprinting time looks like you are throwing a tantrum. That is, you jump up and down with your legs in a near-squat position.

Finally, for long distance runners, you might want to read the book:
Born to Run by Christopher McDougall - 2009. (even if you are a non-runner, it is quite an interesting story!)

I hope this added at least some information to your question.